# Get value from URL in Javascript|jQuery and Symfony2 project

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, symfony, symfony-routing

I need to get some parameters from URL using Javascript/jQuery and I found this nice function:

```
function getURLParameter(sParam) {
    var sPageURL = window.location.search.substring(1),
        sURLVariables = sPageURL.split('&');

    for (var i = 0; i < sURLVariables.length; i++) {
        var sParameterName = sURLVariables[i].split('=');
        if (sParameterName[0] == sParam) {
            return sParameterName[1];
        }
    }
};
```

So I started to use in my code but I'm having some issues since the parameter I'm looking for comes `undefined`. First, this is a Symfony2 project so `Profiler` gives me this information:

```
Request Attributes

Key                             Value
_route_params                   [registro => 1, solicitud => 58]
...
registro                        1
solicitud                       58
```

What I need from here is `registro` and `solicitud`. So what I did at Javascript side was this:

```
console.log(getURLParameter('registro')); // gets undefined
```

But surprise I get `undefined` and I think the cause is that `registro` is not present at URL which is `http://project.dev/app_dev.php/proceso/1/58/modificar` but it's present in the REQUEST. How I can get the `registro` and `solicitud` values from whithin Javascript? I need to send those parameters to a Ajax call, any advice?

Comment: split the url segments after `.php`

Comment: @charlietfl example?

Comment: could also pass a variable from php to javascript that contains the url params when page loads

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this function:

```
function getParameters(){
    var url = window.location.href; //get the current url
    var urlSegment = url.substr(url.indexOf('proceso/')); //copy the last part
    var params = urlSegment.split('/'); //get an array
    return {registro: params[1], solicitud: params[2]}; //return an object with registro and solicitud
}
```

Then you can call the function and use the values:

```
var params = getParameters();
console.log(params.registro);
console.log(params.solicitud);
```

Comment: The function looks good but is restricted to only this case and the idea is to make it _macro_ so that works for any parameter, not only for these two, have you any better ideas regarding this?

Comment: If you want to write a function for general purpose you need to include each parameter's name in the URL for example: /registro/1/solicitud/48 in order to get key - value pairs

Comment: Another thing you can do is split the entire URL and if you know the position of each parameter in the array, you can get the value of each one.